# Paypal Express L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESCm does not show on receipt

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

I am using the default Paypal Express extension for OpenCart.  It works and transactions are processed without a problem.  In the controller I can see both `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` and `SetExpressCheckout` methods taking place and logging the curl requests shows `ACK=Success` as response.

The trouble is that even though I am submitting line item descriptions via `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0`, `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1`, etc field it does not show up on the receipt - only the product name and number.

The [Docs Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) seem to indicate this field should be accepted but I can't for the life of me figure out why it doesn't show in the final transaction details.

Comment: Can you post an entire call? A lot of times answers to this kind of problem are contextual.

Comment: As I said this is the default OpenCart extension.  and can be downloaded here : http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=download/download/success&download_id=36.  I'm not going to post hundreds of lines of code for something that is publicly available.  Nothing has been modified from the original.

Comment: Unfortunately, the DESC fields have never really done anything in my experience.  If you want to show a "description" you'll have to do that with a combination of the name and item number fields.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewAngell - that's what I've done but it makes no sense.  With paypal standard I was able to pass options and option values and those fields are reflected when I pull transaction details through the API.  Isn't there a way to pass description or options with paypal express?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  It's one of the rare cases where Standard has something that Express does not.  You could pass an invoice ID in the Express request, though, and then save all the necessary details in your database with that invoice.  That way you can easily pull those details back out using the ID.